# complex crons for shared hosting

Tags: apache, cron

I have an app which displays the latest scores in football games. Every 15 minutes, a cron runs to check if a game has started. If it has, another cron needs to start which runs every 30 seconds for the next 2 hours (this cron queries an API to get latest incidents for a game). Im on shared hosting with Plesk and there is no ssh access. Plesk appears to just offer very simple cron management to schedule the execution of a script every x minutes. What is the best solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Have the 30 seconds cron running every 30 seconds (also in times where there is no game) and check inside the script (which is run by this cron) if you are inside your 2 hour timeframe - if yes do the work else end the script

Comment: Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: That is the easiest solution I can think of.